# Version info is not correct from iTunes (Programatically Objective-c)

Tags: ios, objective-c, version-control, app-store

I have implemented some code to check if appStore version is higher than current app version and in that case to show popup to user to update.

I am using below code :-

```
NSString *bundleIdentifier = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
NSString *appStoreURL = [@"http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId="stringByAppendingString:bundleIdentifier];

// Get the main bundle of the app so that we can determine the app's version number
NSDictionary *infoDict = [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary];
NSString *appVersion = [infoDict objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"]; // example: 1.0.0

NSData *dict = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL 
URLWithString:appStoreURL]];
NSError* error;
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dictoptions:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSLog(@"%@", json);
```

And when i am getting contents from URL programatically then it gives version "2.5". Please refer below :-

[image]

But when i download text file from browser it shows me version "2.6" Please refer below the screenshot from Textedit.

[image]

Anyone faced the same issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will take usually 6-8 hours to get the new version of app programmatically. Currently, I am using the same code in my app and its working fine. Your code is fine just wait to get the correct dictionary from Apple lookup URL.

Answer (score 0):

> It may be solved your problem I did in swift 3

```
    let currentAppVersion = Bundle.main.infoDictionary
    Alamofire.request("http://itunes.apple.com/jp/lookup/?id=app_Id", method: .get, parameters: nil, headers: nil).responseJSON { response in
        if let value = response.result.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            let versionNum = value["results"]?.value(forKey: "version") as? NSArray
            if versionNum?[0] as! String != currentAppVersion?["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as! String {
                self.alertForUpdateApp(versionNo: versionNum?[0] as! String)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks my code is working. It was just a delay from iTunes.

Comment: Ok, Thats great.